# Code doesn't work when deploying on Server

Tags: asp.net, excel-interop

I have written the following code to export data to excel.
This code works fine on local,but when we deploy this code on Server (UAT),it doesn't work.
 If we  restart server,   it works for a while but again after a while  it fails.

Code:

```
public void ExportToExcelFunction(string FlName, DataTable mydt, string DispColName, string BindCols)
    {
        Excel.Application xlObj = new Excel.Application();
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlObj.Visible = false;
        //vinod
        string filepath = Server.MapPath("Export");
        string strFlName = filepath + "\\Master.xlsx";

        Excel.Workbook xlWB = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(strFlName, 0, true, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, true, 0, true);
        Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWB.ActiveSheet;

        int cols = mydt.Columns.Count;
        int rows = mydt.Rows.Count;

        //Added for export to excel
        try
        {
            //For Column
            string[] strCols = DispColName.Split(',');
            for (int i = 1; i <= strCols.Length; i++)
            {
                if (strCols[i - 1].Length > 0 && strCols[i - 1] != null)
                    xlSheet.Cells[1, i] = Convert.ToString(strCols[i - 1]);
            }

            // for Row   
            string[] strColBind = BindCols.Split(',');
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < strColBind.Length; c++)
                {
                    xlSheet.Cells[r + 2, c + 1] = mydt.Rows[r][strColBind[c]];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


        String newFlName = "\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "_" + FlName + ".xls";
        xlWB.SaveAs(filepath + newFlName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, "", "", false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, true, false, "", true);

        xlWB.Close(true, oMissing, oMissing);
        xlObj.Quit();

        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"" + filepath + newFlName + "");
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = " + FlName + ".xls");
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/download";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();

    }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: It's possibly the server doesn't have permissions to write to the file path.

Comment: Do you have Excel on your server?

Comment: not getting any error, just page get refresh......

Comment: You aren't releasing the Interop objects anywhere. Excel process will continue to run. If too many are running, you could potentially have a server crash.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should know.

The first, is that your code appears to be using [Excel Interop Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx), thus it requires Excel to be installed on the server.

The second thing is that using Excel Interop Services on the server side is not supported by Microsoft, [for a number of good reasons](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Instead, I suggest using an alternative library such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) or [Open Office XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124), both of which run on the server side just fine.

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll just check with these libraries.

Comment: I personally found EPPlus very simple and powerful. It's available via NuGet if you're familiar with that.